# 30 minute Transaction Log back up

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I take a transaction log back-up every 30 minutes, but every day at about 05:30 the back-up takes 02:30 and this increases each day. Can anyone help?
[image: Backup sizes and log times]

Comment: Help with what? Do you jave any jobs running at this time?

Answer (score 0):

From the size of the backup, I would guess that there is a scheduled process occurring between 5am and 5:30am that is generating roughly 100x as many transactions as in any other 30 minute period - possibly some processing over the entire database, which is increasing in complexity (and thus generating more transaction logs) as the database grows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply – the issue is the Server is hosted externally and they are trying to say it’s due to the size of our tables. But I’ve checked all our linked servers and extracts and they are all finished well before 05:00. They have a weekly index rebuild but not a daily one.

So I assume it has to be something they are doing internally.

Comment: @Aneilg Can you check the transaction log to see what exactly is happening in that half-hour period? Might be that you see a maintenance process from your host and you can pass it back to them

Comment: Thanks i will check.

Answer (score 0):

Check schedule of your maintenance plans. You might be running re-indexing job that time.